# why does this cause :show to get no layout at all: layout 'admin', :except => [:show]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render

why does this cause :show to get no layout at all:  layout 'admin', :except => [:show]

Is this the intended behavior? I'm forced to put a render :layout => 'application' in an otherwise empty def show end.

Shouldn't the show action default to the base layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually surprised me a bit and I had to go to the source to check. The answer is no, it does/should not default to the application layout.  The conditions passed instead are used to determine if the action has a layout *at all*, hence the name of the mixed in method [action_has_layout?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb#L191) (Rails 3).

I'd half expected it to behave like `respond_to`, which you can call multiple times to build up the conditions for different actions.

In any case you can easily handle this by sending a method to `layout` containing your logic (via a proc or a symbol referencing method), rather than defining an empty action simply to render a different layout.

For example:

```
layout :determine_layout

...

def determine_layout
  # show gets application, the rest get admin
  params[:action] == 'show' ? 'application' : 'admin'

  # or, returning true would probably do it (and be more flexible in case 
  # the rest of your app swapped layouts to something other than application)
  params[:action] == 'show' || 'admin'
end
```

Comment: I came to this same conclusion. I find this behavior counter-intuitive, a bit. Thanks for your time and help.